# I am learning python. I am seeking insights for this program. Given an int array length 2, return True if it contains a 2 or a 3

Tags: python

```
def has23(nums):
    if (2 or 3) in nums:
        return True
    else: 
        return False
```

result is coming out right for majority part. 
but for `has23[3,3]` or `[3,9]` it is coming false.
I have 'or' argument in the code, shouldn't it mean that it will look for 2 and 3 more and n will give true if it finds any of it.
please tell me, what concept, I am missing over here?

Comment: It's operator priority, that you're missing. `(2 or 3)` is executed first and results in `2`, than you're checking `if 2 in nums`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581837/return-true-if-array-contains-a-2-or-a-3 too

Answer (score 4):

```
def has23(nums):
    return (2 in nums) or (3 in nums)
```

the expression `(2 or 3)` returns the value 2 so the list [3,3] would not pass.

Answer (score 1):

`2 or 3` evaluates to `2`, so you're checking if `2` is in `nums`.  Instead, say `if 2 in nums or 3 in nums:`.  You don't really need the `if` statement, however, because you can just return the results of the expression:

```
return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check each element explicitly if it is 2 or 3:

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i in (2, 3):
            return True
    return False
```

Another way would be using generators:

```
def has23(nums):
    return any(i in (2,3) for i in nums)
```

Comment: That isn't quite as concise as `if 2 in nums or 3 in nums`.

Comment: Would be boring if everyone posted the same answer. It's a way to do it not the only way. ;-)

Comment: @zondo- But I included an alternative to include ``any`` and a ``generator`` :-)

Comment: I definitely prefer that alternative.  I think list comprehension and generator expressions are my favorite features of Python.

Answer (score 0):

you should do this instead, it'll do the logic you want.

```
def has23(nums):
     if 2 in nums or 3 in nums:
          return True
     else:
          return False
```

Comment: Do not write a test to return the same result (a boolean)